# Change default smtp settings of chatwoot server

Tags: chatwoot

i installed chatwoot.
Then i added an inbox and invited a friend.
this friend did not receive the invite email.
I guess the smtp settings are to be changed but i dont find them in the administration.
Are they in some conf or env file ?
please advise